# Core Data 64 bit transition

Tags: ios, core-data

In the 32-bit systems run correctly, when running in 64-bit system environment (5s), the following warning appears.

```
CoreData: warning: Property 'type' is a 64 bit scalar type on class 'EOTProduct' that does not match its entity's property's 32 bit scalar type.  Implicit coercion to 32 bits in the database is not recommended.
CoreData: warning: Property 'setType:' is a 64 bit scalar type on class 'EOTProduct' that does not match its entity's property's 32 bit scalar type.  Implicit coercion to 32 bits in the database is not recommended.
......
```

I think the type of Core Data attribute can not dynamically changed, then I should choose Integer 32 or Integer 64?
If I choose Integer 32, then it should not be adapted to a 64-bit environment. If I choose Integer 64, then the 32-bit systems will waste a lot of memory?
I have not thought of a good solution, if someone has already solved this problem, Can you share how you solve it? Thank you!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about too stupid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in the position to migrate the data model from NSInteger to NSNumber you should go that route.

Otherwise, if you are stuck with an integer, define it like:

```
@interface  EOTProduct
@property (nonatomic) int32_t type;
@end

@interface EOTProduct (PrimitiveAccessors)
- (NSNumber *)primitiveType;
- (void)setPrimitiveType:(NSNumber*)value;
@end
```

// -----

```
@implementation  EOTProduct
// thereis no >@dynamic type< here
-(int32_t)type {
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"type"];
    NSNumber *tmpValue = [self primitiveType];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"type"];
    return (tmpValue != nil) ? [tmpValue intValue] : 0.0; // Or a suitable representation for nil.
}

-(void)setType:(int32_t)value {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"type"];
    [self setPrimitiveType:[NSNumber numberWithInt:value]];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"type"];
}
@end
```

In your code when accessing the attribute remember to treat it as `int32_t` not as NSInteger. As you have found an `NSInteger` will be a 64bit on a iPhone 5s and a 32bit on the older devices. Treating it as `int32_t` will avoid strange overflow errors and such.

I did chose above solution because migrating was causing more headaches. And here was no noticeable impact on memory consumption wrt. to the ints.